# Does releasing hydroxyl (OH) into the air purify it safely?

Tags: environmental-health

Companies like Air Oasis have products that [promise](https://inspiredliving.com/airpurifiers/hydroxyl-ions.htm) to purify the air by:

> The Air Oasis brands of Air Purifiers that we carry use a unique nano Nickle catalytic hydration process to create powerful purifying hydroxyls, or hydroxyl ions (OH), which are, in turn, used to create additional friendly oxidizers to purify the air.

A [kickstarter project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/88902365/brighten-up-the-air-led-air-purifier-hydroxyl-ion?ref=category) claims:

> An international study being conducted over the Indian ocean which, in part, measured hydroxyl ion levels, led a team of atmospheric experts to conclude that without hydroxyl ions, air pollution can remain at toxic and harmful levels for much longer, increasing the likelihood of negative effect on humans.

Provided the technology can actually release the hydroxyl, does this make the air healthy for humans?

Comment: Hmm, it might be for combating the acids in polluted air since OH- is a base.

Comment: Hydroxyl radicals so seem to help clean pollutants in the troposphere - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyl_radical - not sure where the Air Oasis purifier is being applied (like in the home). I'm not sure you want to be near the source of a highly reactive radical